# Php code highlight in Jekyll kramdown don't work

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I'm using Jekyll with kramdown and pygments, it work fine for javascript or python code but When I create php like:

```
{% highlight php %}
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode(array(
    'jsonrpc' => "2.0",
    'result' => $result,
    'id' => $request->id,
    'error' => null
));
{% endhighlight %}
```

Each line is one span with `x` class:

```
<code class="language-php" data-lang="php"><span class="x">header('Content-Type: application/json');</span>
<span class="x">echo json_encode(array(</span>
<span class="x">    'jsonrpc' =&gt; "2.0",</span>
<span class="x">    'result' =&gt; $result,</span>
<span class="x">    'id' =&gt; $request-&gt;id,</span>
<span class="x">    'error' =&gt; null</span>
<span class="x">));</span></code>
```

Why I don't have tokens with different classes for php code?

Comment: Did you try adding `<?php` to the beginning of the block?

Comment: @Maerlyn It work, it's weird that's required. You can add answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to forget the **php** opening tag at the beginning of you code block, you have to set the Pygments **startinline** parameter to true.

```
{% highlight php startinline=true %}
```

See [Pygments documentation](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/)

Comment: Great. Today I had the same issue and now I know. Thanks again David!

Answer (score 2):

As of Aug 8, 2016, From https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1633#issuecomment-238383509

> We don't support Pygments anymore. We use Rouge.

The new syntax is as follows:

````
```php?start_inline=true

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode(array(
    'jsonrpc' => "2.0",
    'result' => $result,
    'id' => $request->id,
    'error' => null
));

```
````

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. The ```php?start_inline=true``` is printed within the code block.

Comment: @JCarlos you must have some other plugins interfering. Try the default jekyll example on gitlab pages https://gitlab.com/pages/jekyll

Comment: I don't remember me adding plugins. And my project doesn't have a ```_plugins``` folder. Can I use the Gitlab example in Github pages? Thank you.